# React Hooks: what is the correct way to handle async setState inside component ? (uploadProgress axios)

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hooks, setstate

We want to post multiple files in parallel and display upload progress.

Our first attempt to solve it was to use setState and the previous state in uploadProgress callback:

```
const FileUpload = () => {
  const [pendingUploads, setPendingUploads] = useState({});

  // For clarity: files = Record<string, {id: string, progress: string, data: FormData}>
  const handleChange = files => {
    setPendingUploads(files);

    const handleUploadProgress = (progressEvent, id) => {
      const percentCompleted = (progressEvent.loaded * 100) / progressEvent.total;

      // Problem: pendingUploads is always empty, we do not get the updated value from last update 
      setPendingUploads({
        ...pendingUploads,
        [id]: {
          ...pendingUploads[id],
          progress: `${percentCompleted}%`
        }
      });
    };

    files.forEach(file => {
      axios.post("/files", file.data, {
        onUploadProgress: e => handleUploadProgress(e, file.id)
      });
    });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        {_.map(pendingUpload, (pendingUpload, idx) => (
          <div key={idx}>
            {pendingUpload.id}: {pendingUpload.progress}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>

      <input multiple type="file" onChange={handleChange} />
    </>
  );
};
```

pendingUploads is always empty so the progress value is display for only 1 file at a time.

What would be the correct way to do it ? We have 2 working example so far:

**1) Solution 1**

- Keep a map of pending upload in state (pendingUploads)
- Trigger a progress update (progressUpdate) using setState inside handleUploadProgress (axios callback)
- Update pendingUploads in useEffect when progressUpdate change

```
const FileUpload = () => {
  const [pendingUploads, setPendingUploads] = useState({});
  const [progressUpdate, setProgressUpdate] = useState({ id: "", value: "" });

  useEffect(() => {
    setPendingUploads({
      ...pendingUploads,
      [progressUpdate.id]: {
        ...pendingUploads[progressUpdate.id],
        progress: progressUpdate.value
      }
    });
  }, [progressUpdate]);

  const handleUploadProgress = (progressEvent, id) => {
    const percentCompleted = (progressEvent.loaded * 100) / progressEvent.total;
    setProgressUpdate({ id, value: `${percentCompleted}%` });
  };

  // files = Record<string, {id: string, progress: string, data: FormData}>
  const handleChange = files => {
    setPendingUploads(files);
    files.forEach(file => {
      axios.post("/files", file.data, {
        onUploadProgress: e => handleUploadProgress(e, file.id)
      });
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        {_.map(pendingUploads, (pendingUpload, idx) => (
          <div key={idx}>
            {pendingUpload.id}: {pendingUpload.progress}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>

      <input multiple type="file" onChange={handleChange} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

**2) Solution 2**

- Mutate the files in uploadProgress callback and use the mutated value to update the state of component

```
const FileUpload = () => {

  const [pendingUploads, setPendingUploads] = useState({});

  // files = Record<string, {id: string, progress: string, data: FormData}>
  const handleChange = files => {
    const handleUploadProgress = (progressEvent, id) => {
      const percentCompleted = (progressEvent.loaded * 100) / progressEvent.total;
      files[id].progress = `${percentCompleted}%`;
      setPendingUploads({ ...files });
    };

    files.forEach(file => {
      axios.post("/files", file.data, {
        onUploadProgress: e => handleUploadProgress(e, file.id)
      });
    });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        {_.map(pendingUpload, (pendingUpload, idx) => (
          <div key={idx}>
            {pendingUpload.id}: {pendingUpload.progress}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>

      <input multiple type="file" onChange={handleChange} />
    </>
  );
};
```

Any feedback or working example showing best practice for this particular case are welcome.

Thanks

Comment: A version of Solution 1 actually worked great for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use pendingUploads const inside response callbacks, cause it will reference an outdated version. Instead, consider using previous state setState signature like that: `setPendingUploads((prevPendingUploads) => {return {...prevPendingUploads, /* updates here */}}`

Comment: FTR: the "previous state setState signature" feature is officially called [functional updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates)